Confused on how to create a boxplot with percentages
I'm trying to create a side by side boxplot between two columns 'Total' and 'Region'. All dtypes are "object" however I stripped the '%' from the values in 'Total' and typecasted the column into float64, yet I'm still getting areas and have no clue what to do. I'm new to python and pandas so it very well might be something obvious, either way any help would be greatly appreciated!
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("cleaned-A1data.csv")

df["Total"] = df["Total"].str.rstrip('%')
df = df.astype({'Total': 'float64'}).dtypes

df.boxplot(column=['Total'], by=['Region'])

outputs: 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'

it should be df = df.astype({'Total': 'float64'}) instead of df = df.astype({'Total': 'float64'}).dtypes (with the latter you get a Series of dtypes).

the code mistakenly tries to use the dtypes property, which returns a Series, to call the boxplot method. This issue arises from the line
 df = df.astype({'Total': 'float64'}).dtypes

Try this:
df["Total"] = df["Total"].str.rstrip('%').astype('float64')

df.boxplot(column='Total', by='Region', grid=False)

